# Can't Change CssClass From Code Behind

Tags: asp.net, css, webforms

This has to be the simplest thing in the world but it just isn't working.

I have an outer div to which I want to apply a class to make its display style = none so that it hides all the content within it.  It's actually an asp:panel element so I'm assuming I can just set control.CssClass = "my-hidden-class" in the code behind.

I'm actually setting this on a button click handler(depending on certain conditions)  But the class is never applied.  When I inspect the div element in Firebug it doesn't even have a class attribute.  It appears exactly as it is in the .aspx markup (the actual css class is fine & gets applied when I add it declaratively).

Also, I can see the class applied if I set CssClass in the prerender method on the initial get request.  So I thought maybe I'll put all the logic in prerender and update the Css Class accordingly.  This also doesn't work - the class gets applied on the initial get ok but I can't change it subsequently.

So, to sum up it seems I can't apply class from code behind at all in the event handler and I can only apply it in prerender for the intial get request & this value is persisted on all postbacks.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:  Here's the code -

aspx:

```
        <asp:panel runat="server" ID="TariffContainer"><!--this is the div I want to toggle-->
        <cms:ContentBlock ID="currentTariffsInfo" SkinID="Public/OurPrices/CurrentTariffsInfo" runat="server" />
        <ucTcrPanel:tcrpanel ID="tcrpanel" PagingEnabled="true" runat="server"  />

       <div class="quick-price">
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CausesValidation="false"  ID="QuickEnergyPrice" OnClientClick="Javascript:return false;" CssClass="button subcontent"><span>Get a quick energy price</span></asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
        <div class="not-for-sale">
        <cms:ContentBlock ID="preservedTariffsLinkInfo" SkinID="Public/OurPrices/PreservedTariffsLinkInfo" runat="server" />              
            <p>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CausesValidation="false" ID="ViewNotAvailableTariffs" OnClick="RedirectToUnavailableTariffs" cssclass="arrow">View tariffs not available for sale</asp:LinkButton>
            </p>
        </div> 
    </asp:panel>
```

Code Behind:

```
        protected void PostCodeChange_BtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValid)
        {
            tcrpanel.ApplyPostcodeUpdate(postcode.EnteredPostCode);
            tcrpanel.TcrUpdatePanel.Update();
        }
        else
        {
            TariffContainer.CssClass = "formContentHidden";
        }
    }
```

Update - The button click event is coming from a user control & this is wired up to trigger an update on an update panel - i.e. a partial postback is happening.  I'm doing this hiding & showing of the div in the containing aspx page & even though all the server side page events are executing I'm guessing that the content of the page isn't getting re-rendered so I'm not seeing my changes.

The Solution - I ended up squirting a bit of javascript down from the server:

```
    protected void PostCodeChange_BtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            tcrpanel.ApplyPostcodeUpdate(postcode.EnteredPostCode);
            tcrpanel.TcrUpdatePanel.Update();
    }
```

Then in the tcrpanel user control code behind:

```
    public void ApplyPostcodeUpdate(string postcode)
    {
        if (IsValid)
        {
            BuildStartUpScript("showTariffContainer();");
        }
        else
        {
            BuildStartUpScript("hideTariffContainer();");
        }
    }

    private void BuildStartUpScript(string functionCall)
    {
        StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
        script.AppendLine("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        script.AppendLine(functionCall);
        script.AppendLine("</script>");
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(pnlUpdateTcr, pnlUpdateTcr.GetType(), "HideTariffContainerScript", script.ToString(), false);
    }
```

Then in the included JS file:

```
   function hideTariffContainer() {
          $("div.formContentVisible").toggleClass().toggleClass("formContentHidden");
    }

    function showTariffContainer() {
          $("div.formContentHidden").toggleClass().toggleClass("formContentVisible");
```

}

Comment: Can you put the relevant code up? Would help to identify the problem.

Comment: Never had issue with changing classes from code. Are you using skin?

Comment: @afzalulh - yes, using skins but it shouldn't have any impact here

Comment: Unfortunately, it has. Try not to use skin, or change classes in jquery.

Comment: @afzalulh Do you know how/why using skins has an impact?  Unfortunately I have to use skins as I'm working on an existing site that uses them.  Could do it in JQuery but code behind would be cleaner since the toggling of the div is dependent on a custom server validation routine.

Comment: @afzalulh - I misunderstood.  we're not using skins in the traditional sense.  There are different skin files for different brands but all they do is define CMS content - there's no impact on CSS at all

Comment: @BROTES DE GERMINADOS - In your case skin file has nothing to do... I have tested your code removing the controls inside panel and it is working fine. Yes, I believe your update answers your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suspected, the problem was that a partial postback was occurring in which only the contents of the update panel were being re-rendered.

That said, all the server side page lifecycle events were still being invoked.  This is what confused me as I could debug and see the CssClass being applied but not being rendered in the html.  Just the way Asp.Net update panels work I guess.

Comment: I have the same problem, when i remove the update panel, i am able to change css class, any updates on how to make this happen with the update panel?