# How to properly hide/show asp:Panel with other server controls in it

Tags: css, asp.net, webforms

So I'm working on an `ASP.NET Web Forms` application. I have :

```
`<asp:Panel ID="MyPanel" runat="server">'
```

Inside this panel I have other controls like `Repeaters`, `textboxes` etc, etc and on `(!IsPostBack)` I determine weather to show or not the entire panel by doing so:

```
 if (theClient.CType == "1")
   {
     MyPanel.CssClass == "display-none"
   }
```

Where `display-none` is defined like this:

```
.display-none {
    display: none;
}
```

However under some conditions I want to show this whole panel again and since I set the repeaters and stuff like that on `(!IsPostBack)` I would like to have all those set up. I'm not entirely sure how exactly those visibility properties are working, but what I need is the `HTML` markup to be rendered, the controls to be initialized with the correct data but just to have this hidden on the page but still active.

So having this in mind when the condition to show the panel is met I do this:

```
 MyPanel.CssClass = string.Empty;
```

But.. nothing happens. I'm not entirely sure, if I'm removing the style correctly, if this is the correct `CSS` style that I should be using for what I need to accomplish.

So how can I do this?

Comment: Why not simple do `MyPanel.Visible = true/false`; this way it not dependand on CSS and simple won't render at all if invisible

Comment: In fact I tried exactly this and I didn't get `MyPanel` I thought it's wasn't rendered sicne the beginning. In fact I'm not sure what exactly happened but if the first time I hide the panel then I can't show it with simply returning `Visible = true`.

Answer (score 0):

In aspx page:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .displayPanel
    {
        display:block;
    }

    .hidePanel
    {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

In code behind:

```
if (condition)
{
    MyPanel.CssClass = "displayPanel";
}
else
{
    MyPanel.CssClass = "hidePanel";
}
```

Comment: The problem is that when I change the `CssClass` in code behind it's not automatically changed on the view..

Comment: sorry, it is unclear. What do you mean by CSS is not changed on the View?

Comment: do you want to hide/display on client side or from server side? Above code is for server side and you will see class based on the condition in the rendered HTML. But if you want to hide on client side, you may use similar logic using javascript, but you won't be able to seen in rendered HTML.

Comment: I found this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144011/cant-change-cssclass-from-code-behind This is exactly my issue and the solution also.

Comment: Mmm, the panel that I'm working with is an ordinary panel. But the call comes form control inside `UpdatePanel` and obviously this cause all the problems. However, thanks for your time. I had to describe my setup better.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that an `<asp:Panel>` control gets rendered as a `<div>` to the client. Therefore if there is no content inside the div it won't be displayed on the client. Make sure all your other content like repeaters and textboxes etc Visibility properties are set to true (which is default) so that they will be there when the page is rendered. Also, when you set an asp elements visibility to false, it is not actually rendered on the page. You will have no access to the elements via JavaScript or jQuery etc.

As already mentioned, you can use `(!IsPostBack)` to change the Visible=true/false after doing whatever processing on the server. The only time you should really use the CSS tricks are if you need the element on the client to process with some jQuery or JavaScript.
Have you tried this:

```
if(theClient.CType == "1")
{
   MyPanel.Visible == true;
}
```

Of course you would need to change your markup to:

`<asp:Panel ID="MyPanel" runat="server" Visible=false ></asp:Panel>`